# Output Laravel variable into Ajax Callback to activate another Ajax Function

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve here is quite complicated.

I want to be able to use one Ajax function throughout my website to control the updating of information. Basically, a universal update script which'll activate on a form submission.

However, the issue I'm having is, I also want specific forms to also perform another function on the ajax success callback.

So, for example, I click update on personal information, that'll then update the database and on the success callback, it'll also call another function which I set in the Laravel response back to the Ajax.

The function in the success callback will then update the personal information section with the new data.

So, in laymans terms. I'll setup a function in jQuery/Ajax to update certain information but have the Laravel push that function name to the Ajax Success. Thus making the update script universal.

Please see current code below:

**Laravel**

```
return ['success' => true, 'function_name' => 'updtPersonal', 'msg' => '<i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i> You successfully updated your personal statement', 'data' => $request];
```

**Ajax**

```js
$('.ajaxUpdt').on('submit',function(e){
 var action = $(this).attr('action');
 var method = $(this).attr('method');
 $.ajaxSetup({
  header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
 })
 e.preventDefault(e);
 $.ajax({
  type: method,
  url: action,
  data:$(this).serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
   success(data.msg);
   var func_name = (data.function_name);
   /* I NEED TO MAKE THE func_name VARIABLE BE A FUNCTION */
  },
  error: function(msg){
   fail("Fail");
  }
 });
});
```

Any help would as always, be much appreciated!

Cheers

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return response()->json(
    [
        'success' => true, 
        'function_name' => 'updtPersonal', 
        'msg' => '<i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i> You successfully updated your personal statement', 
        'data' => $request
    ], 200
);
```

**Ajax**

```
  success: function(data){
       if(data.success == true) {
          //do something or call your function 
          console.log(data.msg);
       }
   },
```

Comment: Hi Rimon, thanks for your answer. The Laravel side seems to be working fine, it's getting the function name executed in the Ajax Success callback I'm having issues with. How can I call that function name from the Laravel in to the Ajax Callback?

Comment: e.g. `function updtPersonal(data) { // do something }` and call it on ajax success like so. `updtPersonal(data.result);`.

Comment: Hi Rimon, the function name to be executed is dealt within the Laravel though as a variable. I'd have to make the function name from the Laravel an ajax variable, then use that variable as a function, I'm not sure how to do that though.

Comment: Rimon, please see amended Ajax code. Maybe that'll help explain what I mean :) - thanks for your replies

Comment: I'm not sure it's working or not you can try this: `'function_name' => 'updtPersonal()'` and create the function inside `script` and call it on ajax success `data.function_name;`

Comment: So I'd need to do something like: `success: function(data){
    success(data.msg);
    data.function;
   },` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure this out. I'd appreciate if anyone could suggest a better way if possible though please:

**Laravel**

```
Route::get('/edit/get_personal_statement', function(Request $request) { 
    $user = Auth::user();
    $cv = DB::table('cvs')->where('cv_id', '=', $user->primarycv)->value('personal_statement');
    return ['success' => true, 'function' => 'psupdt', 'msg' => 'Route Found', 'result' => $cv, 'data' => $request];
});
```

**Ajax**

```
    $('.ajaxUpdt').on('submit',function(e){
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        var method = $(this).attr('method');
        $.ajaxSetup({
            header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        })
        e.preventDefault(e);
        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: action,
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var func_name = data.function;
                window[func_name](data.function);
                success(data.msg);
            },
            error: function(msg){
                fail("Fail");
            }
        });
    });

function psupdt(data) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "edit/get_personal_statement",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $(".personal_statement_content").html(data.result);
        }
    });
}
```